# Pick projection from another layer while using project tool (ArcGIS Model Builder)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, modelbuilder

I am using ArcGIS 10.8.2. I built a model but have a problem.
I want to project my layer with picking projection from another layer in model.
Any good idea for that?

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting any error doing the projection?

Comment: i want to use project tool and i want to take projection from an other layer. i do not konw how to do. @Padmanabha tried to explain with this: https://imgur.com/a/uNLg8ol

Answer (score 0):

You cannot feed into the Project tool's out_coor_system parameter a layer, it is expecting a coordinate system, this is clearly indicated in the [Syntax section](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/project.htm#GUID-529F0CFA-5C94-4229-BD79-507B17C18E71) in the help file.

I think the Project tool is one of those quirky tools that must have all it's parameters set before it can validate, so you can't set up a model with a place holder for that parameter, it needs to be defined before you can validate it.

Assuming the projection you want to project into *never* changes then you can import it from the layer.

Below I import a projection from a layer that is Equidistant Conic to set the Output coordinate system parameter in the Project tool.

[image: Importing a projection]